# iframe that includes a flash movie does not refresh

Tags: flash, caching, iframe, browser-cache

I have a code like this

```
<iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
```

The **index.html** includes a **flash movie**. Every time I update this movie (with the same name) the browser shows the previous movie from browser's cache.

I tried different tricks like : meta headers tahs for no cache, jscript to change the parameter of the index.html file ie index.html?xxxxx but it does not seem to work.

Any ideas ?

George

Answer (score 0):

use parameter in object tags, like

```
<object data="xxx.swf?nocache=ran.gettime() ....
```